# How do I optimize my backtracking solution for matching regexes?

Tags: java, regex, backtracking

Here is a problem i was trying to solve on LeetCode:

```
Given an input string (s) and a pattern (p), implement wildcard pattern matching with support for '?' and '*'.

'?' Matches any single character.
'*' Matches any sequence of characters (including the empty sequence).
The matching should cover the entire input string (not partial).

Note:

s could be empty and contains only lowercase letters a-z.
p could be empty and contains only lowercase letters a-z, and characters like ? or *
```

I have come up with a backtracking solution for this problem, like so,

```
class Solution {

    public boolean isMatch(String s, String p) {
        p = p.replaceAll("\\*+", "*");

        return myIsMatch(s, p);
    }

    public boolean myIsMatch(String s, String p) {
        if(s==null || p == null){
            return false;
        }

        if(p.equals("*")){
            return true;
        }


        int i = 0;
        while(i<s.length() && i<p.length() && s.charAt(i)==(p.charAt(i))){
            i++;

            if(i<s.length() && i>=p.length()){
                return false;
            }
        }

        if(i == s.length() && i == p.length()){
            return true;
        }else if(i != s.length() && i == p.length()){
            return false;
        }else if(i == s.length() && i != p.length()){
            if(p.charAt(i) == '*'){
                return myIsMatch("", p.substring(i+1));    
            }else{
                return false;
            }

        }

        if(p.charAt(i)=='?'){
            if(i+1<s.length() && i+1<p.length()){
                return myIsMatch(s.substring(i+1), p.substring(i+1));    
            }else if(i+1<s.length() && i+1>=p.length()){
                return false;
            }else if(i+1>=s.length() && i+1<p.length()){
                return myIsMatch(s.substring(i+1), p.substring(i+1));
            }else{
                return true;
            }
        }else if(p.charAt(i)=='*'){
            for(int k = i;k<=s.length();k++){
                if(myIsMatch(s.substring(k), p.substring(i+1))){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }else{
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This works well for most of the test-cases, except the following pathological one, for which the program doesn't seem to exit,

```
s = "abbabaaabbabbaababbabbbbbabbbabbbabaaaaababababbbabababaabbababaabbbbbbaaaabababbbaabbbbaabbbbababababbaabbaababaabbbababababbbbaaabbbbbabaaaabbababbbbaababaabbababbbbbababbbabaaaaaaaabbbbbaabaaababaaaabb"

p ="**aa*****ba*a*bb**aa*ab****a*aaaaaa***a*aaaa**bbabb*b*b**aaaaaaaaa*a********ba*bbb***a*ba*bb*bb**a*b*bb"
```

How can I optimize the code to handle such an input? Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that the program doesn't exit. Your problem specifically is that your algorithm doesn't run fast enough for the input that you provided, and you ran out of time.

<s>A backtracking solution isn't the best approach for matching regexes. Your current algorithm I believe has a time complexity of O(N^2) but it could be far better, perhaps with a **dynamic programming** solution. I suggest you rethink your approach.</s>

Actually, now that I think about it the best solution is indeed O(mn).

Edit : The problem is that on top of a backtracking solution which would result in an O(mn) time complexity you're also iterating through the strings in the helper function making it something like O(n^3). Instead of modifying the input strings directly try using memoization to solve the problem.